# Using Regex in SQL Server Computed Column Expression?

Tags: sql-server, regex

Column sData is an alphabetical string, like "abcDefghiJkL". I would like to make a computed bit column, call it bMatchesTwice, that is true for any row whose sData contains any two letters from "abdfm" (ignoring capitalization). Regular expressions seem the easiest way to do this, but I am not sure how to perform the match. How can I implement this?

Comment: `'aaaaa'` will get true or false?

Comment: either is fine, since the source column will never duplicate letters, but for the sake of argument let's say true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you would have to use a case expression and check for the existance of each specific character separately. e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE #T (sData VARCHAR(255));
INSERT #T (sData) VALUES ('abcDefghiJkL'), ('XXXXXXA');

ALTER TABLE #T 
ADD bMatchesTwice AS CASE WHEN 
                        (CASE WHEN sData LIKE '%a%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                        CASE WHEN sData LIKE '%b%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                        CASE WHEN sData LIKE '%d%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                        CASE WHEN sData LIKE '%f%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                        CASE WHEN sData LIKE '%m%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 1 
                    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;

SELECT  *
FROM    #T;
```

It might even be better to have a `MatchCount` Column which is simply:

```
ALTER TABLE #T 
ADD MatchCount AS CASE WHEN sData LIKE '%a%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                    CASE WHEN sData LIKE '%b%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                    CASE WHEN sData LIKE '%d%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                    CASE WHEN sData LIKE '%f%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                    CASE WHEN sData LIKE '%m%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

So from the original sample you would get:

```
sData           MatchCount
-----------------------------
abcDefghiJkL    4
XXXXXXA         1
```

If you are doing the work of checking each one anyway, you may as well make the column more versatile.

Comment: For completness you should add note about default collation. What if it is case sensitive?